# How to execute phpunit in code with shell_exec?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to execute the shell command **phpunit** in laravel framework. So I can show the output in a nicer way within the CMS.

```
$results = shell_exec('phpunit');
```

.

```
$results = shell_exec('phpunit --json-log /path/to/store/file.log');
```

This does not work the output I get is the help from phpunit. I've tried to somehow set the full path, cause public/ is the document root. But no luck.

I've crashed my pc 2 times now with trying different things (some loop I guess).

Anyone that can help me with this problem?

**EDIT**

From the public directory in laravel (/path/to/laravel/public) I can use this command:

```
phpunit --log-json ../storage/logs/tests.log --bootstrap ../bootstrap/autoload.php ../tests
```

to execute the test. This is working. But it's not working when I put it in the shell_exec method like:

```
shell_exec('phpunit --log-json ../storage/logs/tests.log --bootstrap ../bootstrap/autoload.php ../tests');
```

The page keeps loading and loading...

Comment: pass the folder where the tests are to the command

Comment: @gontrollez thank you for your reply. Could you be a bit more specific? Like how do I add the folder to the command? I tried: **phpunit ../tests** also used full path.

Comment: and it didn't work?. You can try redirecting the command output to some file so you can see what happens

Comment: isn't the correct command phpunit --log-json ?

Comment: @peyman.H it is. It stores the output in json format into the specified file. It works in command line from the root directory of my project. But not if executed in php. The document root is then ROOT_PATH/public.

Comment: @gontrollez Done that, works in command line. Not in code. I think it's a document root issue, but I've tried full path.